# ES6 Assign a variable with an arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've just started getting accustomed with ES6 syntax and I was wondering if it was possible to assign to a variable with an arrow function.  I'm writing a basic lightweight AJAX helper library and on a status of 200, I want to return a payload to the user, which I currently do with:

```
var responseData = "";
switch (payload.returnType.toLowerCase()) {
    case "json" : responseData = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText); break;
    case "text" : responseData = httpRequest.responseText; break;
    default : responseData = null; break;
}
callback(null, responseData);
```

This is fine, but I can't help but think I could make this cleaner, if I do:

```
callback(null, () => { switch(payload.returnType.toLowerCase()) { ... });
```

I would expect the `return` statement to send the result of the expression as the 2nd parameter in my callback, however when I console log from the caller it prints the switch statement.

Alternatively I have tried to do:

```
var responseData = () => {
    switch (payload.returnType.toLowerCase()) {
        case "json" : return JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText); break;
        case "text" : return httpRequest.responseText; break;
        default : return null; break;
    }
}
callback(null, responseData);
```

In this case, `responseData` is always empty.  Is it possible to have the return value as my 2nd parameter or have it bound to `responseData` as the result of the arrow function?

Comment: You create a function but do not execute the function.

Comment: You also have to actually return something - you dont need to return if you dont use {} but since your function has () => {} you need to return the value you want.

Comment: @NetaMeta yes sorry, I copy and pasted the first block in my answer, I know I need to return fromt he function to assign :)

Comment: also as for your `callback(null, () => { switch(payload.returnType.toLowerCase()) { ... });`  this will also work if you execute it like so: `callback(null, (() => { switch(payload.returnType.toLowerCase()) { ... }));`

Comment: Just to make it crystal clear: Functions need to be executed to get their return value.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, thats totally an oversight on my behalf, I can't believe I made that mistake!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You create an anonymous function but do not execute it.

For example:

```
var getResponseData = () => {
    switch (payload.returnType.toLowerCase()) {
        case "json" : return JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText); 
        case "text" : return httpRequest.responseText; 
        default : return null;
    }
};
callback(null, getResponseData());
```

Comment: Thank-you, this worked perfectly, and then if I wanted to execute it within the parameter of callback I'd call it as a closure with `(() => { ... })();` right?

Answer (score 13):

Even shorter with a self-executing function:

```
const res = (() => {
  return 'something'
})()
```

or even shorter if it's a one-liner:

```
const res = (() => 'something')()
```

Or with your code:

```
var getResponseData = (() => {
  switch (payload.returnType.toLowerCase()) {
    case "json" : return JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText); 
    case "text" : return httpRequest.responseText; 
    default : return null;
  }
})();
```

You can clearly see the difference in this snippet:

```js
const res1 = () => {
  return 'something'
}

const res2 = (() => {
  return 'something'
})()

const res3 = (() =>  'short something')()

console.log(res1)
console.log(res2)
console.log(res3)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your hunch is right, but you're on the wrong track, imho. What I think you want to do is create a map of response types to callbacks:

```
let parsers = new Map([
    ["json", JSON.parse], 
    ["text", (text) => text], 
    ["_", () => null]
]), t = payload.returnType.toLowerCase();

if (!parsers.has(t)) {
   t = "_";
}
callback(null, parsers.get(t)(httpRequest.responseText))
```

What makes this subjectively "cleaner" is that you separate logic from implementation. You can move the parser definition anywhere without affecting the code. That's why switch statements feel "unfunctional" (or undeclarative).

But of course, this all remains a matter of taste :)

Comment: If I use this, I get `Iterator value json is not an entry object`,

Comment: I typed it out the top of my head, let me check for coding errors for a sec. (edit): oh wait I already see the first error, the pairs should be enclosed in an array as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading through the MDN docs on Map now, I really prefer this way over a boring switch...Got it working now, thanks again!

Comment: yeah I think adding the array enclosure around the Map constructor's argument is the only error in there.

Comment: What's the advantage of `Map` over a plan old hash?

Comment: I suspect you mean an object literal. In this particular case it has no real advantage to use Map, but in general there are a number of advantages, in particular that the order of elements is maintained. For objects that is by definition undefined. There are more advantages you can read for example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).